# Flutter IOS Bottomsheet blinking when multiple textfields add and open the keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I have used the bottomsheet at one of my flutter project. It works perfectly on android and IOS simulator. When I run the project on real iPhone I am facing issues. please check attached code and image.

```
_changePasswordBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.w),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            NavigationService().setPopNavigator();
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              setWidth(25),
                              setComonText(
                                'CHANGE PASSWORD',
                                setAlignment: TextAlign.center,
                                style: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                                    fontsize: 18.w,
                                    weight: weight.semibold,
                                    color: C.blackTxt),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  height: 25.w,
                                  width: 25.w,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: C.primaryGreyColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.5.w),
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.close,
                                    color: C.white,
                                    size: 16.w,
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      setHight(25.w),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: C.boxBorderColor),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: editController.signupPassword,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Passsword",
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                                  fontsize: 16.w,
                                  weight: weight.semibold,
                                  color: C.boxBorderColor)),
                          style: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                              fontsize: 16.w, weight: weight.semibold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      setHight(35.w),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: C.boxBorderColor),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: editController.signupNewPass,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "New Passsword",
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                                  fontsize: 16.w,
                                  weight: weight.semibold,
                                  color: C.boxBorderColor)),
                          style: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                              fontsize: 16.w, weight: weight.semibold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      setHight(10.w),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: C.boxBorderColor),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: editController.signupConfirmPass,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Confirm Passsword",
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                                  fontsize: 16.w,
                                  weight: weight.semibold,
                                  color: C.boxBorderColor)),
                          style: CustomTheme().setTextStyle(
                              fontsize: 16.w, weight: weight.semibold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      setHight(50.w),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          setWidth(20.w),
                          Expanded(
                            child: createButton(
                                width: setDeviceWidth() - 40.w,
                                text: 'CANCEL',
                                txtColor: C.white,
                                btnColour: C.primaryGreyColor,
                                onBtnClick: () {
                                  editController.cancelPassword();
                                  NavigationService().setPopNavigator();
                                },
                                fontSize: 14.w,
                                height: 45.w,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.5.w)),
                          ),
                          setWidth(20.w),
                          Expanded(
                            child: createButton(
                                width: setDeviceWidth() - 40.w,
                                text: 'SAVE',
                                txtColor: C.white,
                                onBtnClick: () {
                                  editController.cancelPassword();
                                  NavigationService().setPopNavigator();
                                  modalBottomSheetSuccess(
                                      'Password Saved \nSuccessfully!');
                                  TimerUtils().startTimer(() {
                                    NavigationService().setPopNavigator();
                                  });
                                },
                                fontSize: 14.w,
                                height: 45.w,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.5.w)),
                          ),
                          setWidth(20.w),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

**Attached Image is:**

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` from your code?

Comment: Textfield didn't move up when keyboard opens.

Comment: i think the blink is because any `MediaQuery...` will result a rebuild every time the parameters, like available widht / height etc. are changed. And since opening the keyboard is animated, it will be called many times.